# How to start with a Java - Mobile App (Which platform in Java supports it? )

Tags: java, ide, mobile-application, portable-applications, mobile-os

I am enjoying the coding in Java. 
As going ahead, I want to know how can I start creating Small Mobile Apps by using JAVA. 
Which IDE can support me do it? 
Which Mobile OS supports Java App? 
Please Help me!

Thank you

Comment: You could look at JME2 (Java Micro Edition) and possibly even [CodeName One](http://www.codenameone.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give a try at crossplatform tools such as NeoMAD (http://www.neomades.com), that allow you to develop native applications for the main mobile platforms (Android, iOS, Windows Phone, Windows 8, BlackBerry) with a single Java source code.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously android is the hottest mobile OS which supports Java programming...

If you want to start with android apps... You could use Eclipse ADT.. Please download it from the following link
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
If you would prefer to add the capability to your existing eclipse installation, Please follow the following link.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html
There is an IDE called Android studio, which is the target IDE for android development, but is at its early stages...